# .htaccess rewrite rules runs script multiple times

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This rewrite rule seem to run my cgi script `joppli.bot` 3 times at one request.

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# add trailing slash
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ joppli.bot [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex joppli.bot
```

How can I make a rewrite rule that only starts the cgi script once for evry request?

---

#### The cgi script

```
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
        printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
               "\r\n"
               "<title>FastCGI Hello!</title>"
               "<h1>FastCGI Hello!</h1>"
               "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n",
                ++count, getenv("SERVER_NAME"));
}
```

Comment: Comment out `DirectoryIndex` and clarify how did you verify that web request to `/joppli.bot` is being invoked 3 times?

Comment: Are you aware how browsers request resources from a server? In particular, are you aware how the web page, images on that page, css and javascript files are loaded?

Comment: Yes I'm aware .. but there is no resources loaded .. it's plain text and. Updated the answer with the current running script, not realy.. but it gives an insight to how I know it runs multple times

Comment: I commented out the `DirectoryIndex` @anubhava, fisrt it worked, after a while of updating it's back to 3 calls at a time ... I think something is broken.

Comment: @Erik: I am not really familiar with fcgi, but afaik mod_rewrite does only rewrite things. After it is done rewriting it hands over the rewritten string to Apache and tells it: Do something useful with it! A request to, for example, `/blah` would only rewrite once to `joppli.bot`. I can imagine that if you don't have a favicon, it might rewrite that to joppli.bot as well. If your browser wants to find more files, it might do that as well. Test `RewriteRule ^blah$ joppli.bot` and go to `yoursite.com/blah`. Does this have the same problem?

Comment: If I don't use any htaccess at all and just go to the uri: `/joppli.bot` it works fine.

The output of the script `<h1>It works!</h1><p>Request number 52 running</p>`

Comment: ...and then in FF it seem to work just fine ??? wtf is going on?

Comment: @Sumurai8 the `RewriteRule ^blah$ joppli.bot` has the expected behavier, the count is increased by 1 only.

Comment: Open your Apache access log. Watch what requests your browser is making.

Comment: @Sumurai8 yhea, it's a browser issue .. the access log shows it tryes to fins a favicon and other things, thanks .. I remove the question soon

Comment: Don't delete questions unless they are inherently bad. This question isn't bad (it is readable and it is understandable); you just searched for the solution in the wrong place. I won't be writing an answer since my knowledge of fcgi is minimal; write an answer of your own and accept it. It will help future visitors too.